# Crontab no ejecuta la tarea

Tags: ubuntu, crontab

Al añadir la siguiente tarea a Crontab, no es ejecutada:

```
* * * * * sha256sum -c Ejercicio.sha256 >> /home/user/Escritorio/Ejercicio/example.txt
```

Esta línea de código lo que hace es verificar la integridad de los archivos comparando su checksum con el que previamente se calculó y almacenó en Ejercicio.sha256. Y almacena los resultados en example.txt.

Al ejecutar esa línea manualmente en la terminal, no hay ningún problema: en example.txt se guardan correctamente los resultados.

También, al programar otra tarea en crontab:

```
* * * * * date >> /home/user/Escritorio/ejemplo.txt
```

Crontab funciona correctamente, esa línea de código se ejecuta sin problemas. Por tanto, deduzco que el problema no es de Crontab.

Sin embargo, como dije antes, al añadir a Crontab la primera tarea no se ejecuta correctamente: el archivo example.txt es creado, pero está vacío. Y sigue vacío a pesar de que pasen los minutos.

He tratado de solucionarlo de diversas maneras: programando un script tarea.sh que contuviera

```
#!bin/bash
sha256sum -c Ejercicio.sha256 >> example.txt
```

Y escribir en crontab:

```
* * * * * /home/user/Escritorio/Ejercicio/tarea.sh
```

Y tampoco funcionó.

Otra solución que se me ocurrió y que no funcionó fue la siguiente. En el script tarea.sh:

```
#!bin/bash
sha256sum -c Ejercicio.sha256
```

Y en crontab:

```
   * * * * * /home/user/Escritorio/Ejercicio/tarea.sh >> /home/user/Escritorio/Ejercicio/example.txt
```

El script ejecutado manualmente funcionaba correctamente.

¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema?

Muchas gracias.

**Edición:** ejecuté el siguiente comando

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Y ahora al añadir la tarea a Crontab de la siguiente forma:

```
* * * * * sha256sum -c /home/user/Escritorio/Ejercicio/Ejercicio.sha256 >> /home/user/Escritorio/Ejercicio/prueba.txt
```

En prueba.txt no aparece el resultado esperado (la verificación de la integridad de los archivos), sino que aparece lo siguiente

```
fichero1.txt: FAILED open or read
```

Así que parece que el crontab no termina de funcionar correctamente escribiendo la ruta de Ejercicio.sha256. Comprobé si manualmente funcionaba el comando con la ruta de Ejercicio.sha256 escrita :

```
sha256sum -c /home/user/Escritorio/Ejercicio/Ejercicio.sha256 >> /home/user/Escritorio/Ejercicio/example.txt
```

Y se produce el siguiente error:

```
sha256sum : /home/user/Escritorio/Ejercicio: error de lectura
```

Comment: prueba redireccionando stderr a stdout y al txt `sha256sum -c Ejercicio.sha256 2>&1 >> example.txt`

Comment: tal vez también habría que pasarle el path completo de Ejercicio.sha256

Comment: Y el log de cron, tiene algo sobre esas ejecuciones fallidas?

Comment: Revisando el log de cron, aparece lo siguiente, tanto ejecutando el script tarea.sh como escribiendo el comando directamente en crontab. No MTA installed, discarding output.

Comment: Revisa que el usr sudo tenga permisos de escritura y lectura sobre tu archivo, es decir chmod+775

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de probar diferentes estrategias conseguí que funcionara.

1.Le di permisos de lectura, ejecución y escritura a Ejercicio.sha256

```
chmod 777 Ejercicio.sha256
```

2.Moví los archivos al directorio /home/user (no sé si esto contribuyó realmente a que funcionara pero señalo el detalle por si acaso).

3.Y en crontab:

```
* * * * * sha256sum -c /home/user/Ejercicio.sha256 >> /home/user/example.txt
```

El archivo example.txt se genera correctamente y contiene los resultados que se producen tras ejecutar el comando sha256sum -c Ejercicio.sha256.